# What is the right way to start Authorization Code Flow from identity server login page?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, identityserver4

I'm trying to implement Authorization Code Flow for SPA React client with ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer4.

There are two scenarios:

1) User open SPA app, we check if he has an access token and if he hasn't we generate url like

```
/connect/authorize?
client_id=*client_id*&
redirect_uri=*redirect_uri*&
response_type=code&
response_mode=fragment&
state=*some_state*&
nonce=*some_nonce*&
code_challenge=*code_challenge*&
code_challenge_method=S256&
scope=openid profile email
```

And so Authorization Code Flow starts. This works pretty clear and after all round trips user comes back to SPA app with code then send request for token (include code and code_verifier) then receive it and with happiness in soul continue using our great application.

2) User opens login page directly and here is where I'm stuck. IdentityServer context knows nothing about this user, code challenges etc. because we didn't make request to `/connect/authorize` before going to this page as in normal flow. What's next?

I can generate `/connect/authorize` link directly in login page and do ugly redirect to it and then back to login page (what I don't want to do honestly), but how my SPA app will know what code_verifier I generate here? Of course I can store it in some shared cross-domain cookie, but here should be something better approach I believe.

Another solution I can redirect user from login page to my app, it recognizes that user not authorized and we start scenario #1. Also not my go to approach I think.

What should I do in case user opens my identity server page directly?
Is this possible using Authorization Code Flow or should I consider combine some other flows with this one?

I don't want to use Implicit Flow due to new recommendation from OAuth 2.0 specification.

Comment: +1 VERY nice question! Also I noticed you followed my Materials Modeling Stack Exchange proposal. We are now in the commitment stage and it would be very very helpful if you could click commit! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGFkOGRlMTg1ODg2NTUxZDQ1MDVjZmQyOTg1ZDcxODQzMjc0OGIyMjBhZDM4ZDQ5MzM0MWE1YzZhNDBjMzhlYfHJBfp5EvPDPybryqjeDgXYucHU-wUv4jp4j6imjIfF0 Only about 2.7% of the people fulfill commitment on new proposals anyway so it doesn't matter if you can't participate much, but it would be helpful to get more users committed before the deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a simple answer to this - in your second scenario - if your user opens IDP login page directly, they didn't want to go to your app. It's the same if you were using Google or Facebook or one of the other known IDP's for your SPA and as a user I just went to their login page instead. They couldn't possibly know if my intention was to ever come to login so that I am later redirected to your SPA.

Now having said all that - what you could do to make this work somewhat seamless - is to redirect to your SPA's protected page after the user logs in through Identity Server 4 (that's simple because you own the login pages and there is no OAuth involved here). Your SPA would then be triggered to initiate the OAuth2 flow and would redirect back to Identity Server 4. The user has already logged in just seconds ago here though, so the login procedure would be skipped and user would either be presented with consent page or if your client is configured to skip consent page - user would be redirected back to your SPA with the usual tokens and such.

So to break it down into the flow:

> User Accesses IDS4 Login Page -> User Enters Credentials -> IDS4
>   Authenticates User and Redirects to your SPA protected page -> Your
>   SPA initiates OAuth2 flow and redirects back to IDS4 -> IDS4 displays
>   consent page -> IDS4 issues auth code back to your SPA.

There is ofcourse extra step here that your SPA will exchange auth code for access token, but I omitted it for clarity purpose as it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: That's interesting thoughts. My mind go to a little bit different direction. How about changing flow to process all authorization things on the IdentityServer side (should notice that my IDS4 frontend part also React SPA, so when I say IDS4 page - this is one from IDS4 SPA). Then flow will look something like this:

Comment: User Accesses IDS4 Login Page -> User Enters Credentials -> IDS4 Authenticates User and Redirects to generated by Login Page /connect/authorize/ endpoint -> IDS4 redirect to IDS4 Callback Page -> IDS4 Callback Page gets code and request for access_token -> write token to cookie -> redirect to main SPA app.

Comment: what do you think? In this case we encapsulate whole logic about issuing tokens and leave it for IDS4 and his SPA. Our main SPA just consumes tokens and if token is not there redirects to login page.

Comment: Don't do it, it is only a quirk for the quality of life and convenience that you can have your SPA and IDS4 as the same project. Treat your identity provider and SPA as completely separate entities. I have had a project where we had more than one SPA - so if the user actually logged in IDP - we wouldn't redirect, but instead we had a bunch links to our SPA's.

Comment: But they will separate. I'll try to explain. Look, I have one main SPA and IDS4 server with React front-end (not server-side Razor as in the examples). I don't have consent pages as this is public app and I'm creating auth server for users. So my IDS4 and main SPA are separate things. And for the end users I think will be more friendly to issue all tokens on IDS4 side and make all round trips there. Lets think about IDS4 front-end part as spa-client. Is this make sense?

Comment: It's like pure Implicit or Password flow, but with all the advantages of Authorization Code Flow. I know that this approach not suits for solutions when you need one IDServer for lots of apps in different domains etc. I think for me this will be best UX and security solution. Your thoughts?

Comment: There are no advantages here, your SPA in your flow doesn't play any part in the authentication because it only piggybacks on the fact that it can read the same cookie because it probably is on the same domain as IDS4. If that fits your needs though - go for it- but it is not the architecture and the flow I would recommend.

Comment: Yes, my main SPA will not get any part in the authorization process in this case probably. I know you don't recommend this, but is there any disadvantages that you could mention please?

Comment: Regarding cookie yes, but not the same domain as IDS4. It will be on subdomain like ids4.domain.com and app.domain.com. But I think you mean this also ;)

Comment: Yeah disadvantages are that this twists the OAuth2 flow a lot and is in general an extremely fragile approach. Another disadvantage is that you will be tied to the same domain and you will also need to tweak your IDS4 to issue cookies to *.domain.com without subdomain or else other subdomains won't be able to read it. Also so what happens when token expires and your SPA can't do anything because it doesn't play part in authentication?